# update panel with ClientScriptManager

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

```
<asp:button runat="server" id="a" onClick="a_Click"/>
```

code

```
protected void a_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    string script = "PanelVisiable($('#base')); ";
    script += "$('#message').text(' message  ');";
    script += "$('#message').dialog({modal:true,resizable:false,title:'پیغام',height:80,show:'clip',hide:'explode'});";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "", script, true);

}
```

this code work fine

---

but this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
 <asp:button runat="server" id="a" onClick="a_Click"/>
 </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code

```
protected void a_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    string script = "PanelVisiable($('#base')); ";
    script += "$('#message').text(' message  ');";
    script += "$('#message').dialog({modal:true,resizable:false,title:'پیغام',height:80,show:'clip',hide:'explode'});";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "", script, true);

}
```

but this script does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` method.

See the following MSDN documentation: [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)

It states:

> Registers a startup script block for a control that is inside an
>   UpdatePanel by using the ScriptManager control, and adds the script
>   block to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead of `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`